# I can't create a simple dataBase in EntityFramework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm a realy newbie in EntityFramework and Core.

I want to create a simple DataBase in EntityFramework Core 2.0. The project is a ConsoleApplication that I included it a Microsoft.AspNetCore.All by Nuget package. This is a code:

```
namespace TestEF
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connStr = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SchoolDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        var db = new SchoolContext(SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connStr).Options);
        db.Students.Add(
            new Student()
            {
                LastName = "Miranda",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now,
                FirstMidName = "Guillermo"
            });
        db.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
}
```

I'm loggin into a intranet as username "gmiranda". When I run the project I get the following message error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Cannot open database "SchoolDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'domain\gmiranda'.

What is I doing wrong ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connStr = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SchoolDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        var db = new SchoolContext();
        db.Students.Add(
            new Student()
            {
                LastName = "Miranda",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now,
                FirstMidName = "Guillermo"
            });
        db.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SchoolDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Then open Package Manager Console  and use command Add-Migration FirstMigrarion.
Its add migration to your database with name FirsMigration.
Then use command Update-Database.
Then run your program.

Try use this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db